# 30 ball bearings, five are defective. Choose 10 probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Could someone confirm my solutions for a combinatorics question?

**Question:**

> In a group of 30 ball bearings, 5 are defective.  If 10 of the ball
>   bearings are chosen, what is the probability that:
>
> a) None of them are defective?
>
> b) Exactly two are defective?

**Part (a) Solution:**

1. There are 30 ball bearings and only 10 need to be chosen, so the sample space is $\dbinom{30}{10}$.
2. Since only the non-defective ball bearings are chosen, 10 of the 25 non-defective ball bearings are chosen to make up the set, $\dbinom{25}{10}$.

**Part (a) Answer:** $P = \frac{\dbinom{25}{10}}{\dbinom{30}{10}}$

**Part (b) Solution:**

1. There are 30 ball bearings and only 10 need to be chosen, so the sample space is $\dbinom{30}{10}$.
2. There are exactly two defective ball bearings in the set of 10 chosen ones; thus, two of the defective ball bearings must be chosen from the set of five, $\dbinom{5}{2}$.
3. Afterwards, additional eight ball bearings must be chosen and they must be non-defective, so they must be chosen from the 25 available non-defective ball bearings, $\dbinom{25}{8}$.

**Part (b) Answer:** $P = \frac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{25}{8}}{\dbinom{30}{10}}$

Comment: I can confirm your solution. But the word afterwards is not right. The non-defective balls can be chosen any time within the ten choses.

Comment: @callculus Thanks.  It seemed awfully simple, so it kind of... worried me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've got this.   Your reasoning from first principles is entirely correct.

The keyword is **Hypergeometric Distribution**

> The probability of selecting $k$ favoured items in a sample of size $n$, selected without bias nor repetition, from a population of size $N$ with $K$ favoured items is:
>
> $$\mathsf P(X=k) ~=~\dfrac{\dbinom K k~\dbinom{N-K}{n-k} }{\dbinom{N}{n}}$$

Everything else is just putting in the numbers.   $N=30, K=5, n=10$    Which you did, so, ... there you go.

---

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=0) ~=~ \dfrac{\color{silver}{\dbinom {5} {0}}~\dbinom{25}{10} }{\qquad\dbinom{30}{10}} &,& \mathsf P(X=2) ~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom {5} {2}~\dbinom{25}{8} }{\dbinom{30}{10}} \tag{$\color{green}\checkmark$}~\end{align}$$

---

$\Box\!\!\!\!\raise{0.5ex}\checkmark~$ Community Wiki answer.